# How to get updated DOM after using checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, dom

I know that the title of asking is quite vague. But let's check this page:
https://www.cleaneye.go.kr/user/gongsiCompare.do

So this is one of public data page in Korea which has a data I need in my research.
As you can see, it has some checkbox in ul, and if you check one of the box in left one, the list of checkbox on its right would come up.

So I made a code to check every combinations, and I'll show you the one which cause the problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_LOCATION)
driver.get('https://www.cleaneye.go.kr/user/gongsiCompare.do')

in_type = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='divPcomp']/ul/li")
for in_t in in_type:
    in_t.find_element_by_xpath("./label/input").click()

    region_type = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='divSido']/ul/li")
    for r_t in region_type:
        r_t.find_element_by_xpath("./label/input").click()
```

The problem is, when the code execute

```
r_t.find_element_by_xpath("./label/input").click()
```

it gives ElementNotInteractableException error, maybe cuz DOM didn't revised after it clicked the checkbox in

```
in_t.find_element_by_xpath("./label/input").click()
```

So I've searched how to solve this problem, and most of answers were about using implicit/explicit wait. Before I do that, I put time.wait(30) between click()s, and still it didn't work. So just waiting might not be the solution for this.

As you can see, if you refresh it, the whole page would be reset so... that is not the answer for this as well.

Is there any great solution, or any walk-around it, please enlighten me.
Otherwise, I'll just use mouseclick and keyboard inputting 'tab' haha...

Thanks for your attention to this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your locator is not unique, it finds element that is not visible on screen use :

```
region_type = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='divSido']/ul/li[@class='rowon']")
```

Comment: Ohhhh right. there is rowoff elements which was not ineractable!! shoot, clumsy me.
Thank you for the itchy-scratching answer PDHide! Thanks a lot :)